# How to draw cell borders in imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have a small 2d vector to display:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = np.random.rand(4,10)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='Reds')
```

As folllow:

[image]

But now I want to mark a specific cell, in order to focus the reader on that cell. Because this is of specific interest...

Therefore something like a border of this cell would be nice:

[image]

Does someone know how to archive this with `matplotlib` in a convenient way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put a rectangle at the position of the pixel you want to highlight.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def highlight_cell(x,y, ax=None, **kwargs):
    rect = plt.Rectangle((x-.5, y-.5), 1,1, fill=False, **kwargs)
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    return rect

img = np.random.rand(4,10)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='Reds')

highlight_cell(2,1, color="limegreen", linewidth=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]