# higlighting set of values in pcolor 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hello i want to create a highlighting on a set of values in a 3D plot(`pcolor`).
I didn't find anything on stackoverflow. In [In a matplotlib plot, can I highlight specific x-value ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270981/in-a-matplotlib-plot-can-i-highlight-specific-x-value-ranges) there is a example how to do it on a 2D plot. There they using `axvspan` this works for rectangular  higlighting too but not for othershapes.
The closed i can get to what i need is this...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr0 = np.arange(40)
arr1 = np.arange(20)
arr1lim = 12

a, b = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-20, 20), np.arange(-20, 20))
xyrange = a + b
xyrange = xyrange[:, 5: 25]

range0 = np.where(arr1 <= arr1lim)
range1 = np.where(xyrange >= 0)

overlay = np.zeros_like(xyrange, dtype=np.float)
overlay[range1[0], range1[1]] = 1
overlay[:, range0[0][-1]: -1] = 0
overlay[np.where(overlay == 0)] = None

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(arr1, arr0)
workplot = ax.pcolor(X, Y, xyrange)
ax.pcolor(X, Y, overlay, linewidths=0, alpha=0.4, edgecolor=None)
```

[image: result from script above]

but it looks not as nice as with `axvspan`. Some difficulties i have are:

- Adding `color='red'` option don't change the result.
- the way it shows edges is ugly is isn't a smooth surface

So are there solution(s) for better higlighting?

Comment: The problem with overlaying a plot in a colored 2D plot is that you inevitably will lose information about the original data (it distorts the colors). Perhaps you could try the solution given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56654952/8345628), where `imshow` is used instead of `pcolor` by the way (it is faster and prettier - it allows interpolation :P).

Comment: I agree with you about the lose of information, but for me it is not important it is a graphical representation of my ‘solution’ area. What to me more is a problem but `imshow` ignore axis input. At leas as far as looked at it (https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html).  Combining  both types don’t work either since the `imshow` is below the `pcolor`.

Comment: You can use the `extent` argument of the `imshow` function to set the axis limits, though you are right in the sense that `imshow` only works for regularly spaced data.